# Visualise data from hive database to website page

Tags: php, hadoop, hive, report

I've already load data sensor from device to Hive database. Now i want to make a web page to visualize the data from Hive. But i dont know how to connecting hive with php or maybe any tutorial to visualize data from Hive to web page without using  build platform (horton, cloudera, etc)?

Comment: please first have a look at  [How do I ask a good question?]http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try connect java servlet by jdbc with metastore tables. If you don´t want use java, also you can try with ruby or phyton.